# One-object lax natural transformation

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

A *lax natural transformation* $\alpha$ between two pseudofunctors $F,G: \mathcal{K} \to \mathcal{L}$ between bicategories $\mathcal{K}, \mathcal{L}$ consists of the following data:

- For every object $A \in \mathcal{K}$ a 1-cell $\alpha_A: FA \to GA$ in $\mathcal{L}$,
- For every 1-cell $f: A \to B$ in $\mathcal{K}$ a 2-cell $Gf \circ \alpha_A \Rightarrow \alpha_B \circ Ff$ in $\mathcal{L}$,

subject to axioms, see the references [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/lax+natural+transformation).

Assume now that $\mathcal{K}, \mathcal{L}$ have one object. It is well known that they correspond to monoidal categories $M_{\mathcal{K}}$, $M_{\mathcal{L}}$ and that $F,G$ correspond to [monoidal functors](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+functor) $\widetilde{F}, \widetilde{G}$. Under this correspondence, the data of $\alpha$ will consist of an object $A_\alpha$ in the monoidal category $M_\mathcal{L}$ together with a 1-cell for every object $X$ of $M_\mathcal{K}$:

$$\tilde{\alpha_X}: \widetilde{G} X \otimes A_\alpha \to A_\alpha \otimes \widetilde{F} X,$$
subject to axioms.

In case $A_\alpha$ is equal to the monoidal unit (this means that the original lax natural transformation is an [icon](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/icon)), this becomes an ordinary [monoidal natural transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_natural_transformation).

**Now my question is**: Does this structure have a name in monoidal category literature? Has it been studied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two monoidal functors $F,G: M_{\mathcal K} \to M_{\mathcal L}$ select a way to make $M_{\mathcal L}$ into an $M_{\mathcal K}$-bimodule category. The data $(A_\alpha, \tilde{\alpha})$ is called a *half-braiding* (more precisely, $\tilde{\alpha}$ is a half-braiding on $A_\alpha$) with respect to the bimodule structure. The category of all half-braidings is the *relative Drinfeld centre* of the bimodule. I could not find a textbook source for these words, but they are used by the community, and attested in the literature, e.g. [How does the relative Drinfeld center interact with the relative Deligne tensor product?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285730/how-does-the-relative-drinfeld-center-interact-with-the-relative-deligne-tensor).